# Automatic button pressing without confirmation Django + JS

Tags: javascript, django

tell me, please, there is a button, you select a number and click "send", the number is saved, how to do it so that you just click on the number and it is automatically saved

template

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
    {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

let me know if you need more code to help me.

[image: example]

Comment: with an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form using jquery.
Assuming your field id is id_update, this code should submit the form.
Add this code in html page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_update").change(function(){        
        $("form").submit(); // Submit the form
    });
});
</script>
```